# Calculate loss and profit from percentage

Tags: javascript, percentage

FIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/o1hq1apw/2/

The current BTC price is 2700$.
The price has increased by +34% in 7Days.
I hold 3.011 BTC, how can i calculate my profit?

```
currentPrice = 2700;
percent = 34;
holdings = 3.011;
alert(  calcPec(currentPrice,percent,holdings)  );
```

The current BTC price is 2700$.
The price has increased by -7% in 2Days.
I hold 3.011 BTC, how can i calculate my loss?

```
currentPrice = 2700;
percent = -7;
holdings = 3.011;
alert(  calcPec(currentPrice,percent,holdings)  );
```

```
// This is what i have but it is not correct
function calcPec(currentPrice,percent,holdings)
{
   res = currentPrice*percent/2;
   sum = holdings*res;
   return '$'+sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to divide the percentage by 100 to get a fraction.

```js
// The current BTC price is 2700$.
// The price has increased by +34% in 7Days.
// I hold 3.011 BTC, how can i calculate my profit?

currentPrice = 2700;
percent = 34;
holdings = 3.011;
console.log(calcPec(currentPrice, percent, holdings));


// The current BTC price is 2700$.
// The price has increased by -7% in 2Days.
// I hold 3.011 BTC, how can i calculate my loss?

currentPrice = 2700;
percent = -7;
holdings = 3.011;
console.log(calcPec(currentPrice, percent, holdings));

function calcPec(currentPrice, percent, holdings) {
  const curr = holdings * currentPrice;
  const changed = curr * (1 + (percent / 100));
  return '$' + (changed - curr);
}
```

In future you probably want to define your percentage as a fraction to begin with, to avoid errors like this. So instead of `percent = 34` you'd do `percent = 0.34`

**EDIT** fixed other errors too;

Answer (score 3):

So you hold 3.011 BTC which is currently 2700$ per BTC.
7 days ago the price of on BTC was equal to 100%, now it has risen by 34% so the 2700$ equal 134%.
To calculate the price from 7 days ago you have to divide 2700 by 134%, which is approx. 2014$.
So your earnings are (2700 - 2014) * 3.011 = 2065

Your code should be the following:

```
function calcPec(currentPrice, percent, holdings)
{
    oldPrice = currentPrice / ((100 + percent) / 100);
    sum = (currentPrice - oldPrice) * holdings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the percent value by 100 to the the fraction of the change.

```js
function calcPec(price, percent, holdings) {
    return '$' + (holdings * price * percent / 100).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(calcPec(2700, 34, 3.011));
console.log(calcPec(2700, -7, 3.011));
```

Comment: This returns the value of the holdings after the change, not the profit/loss